# Combine, Group and Rename

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

Here is my current formula:

```
if left ({Command.NextDueDate},7) = "2016-01" then "January'16"
else if left ({Command.NextDueDate},7) = "2016-02" then "February'16"
...
else if left ({Command.NextDueDate},7) = "2017-01" then "January'17"
```

I take date Strings from my database formatted like `2016-01-05`, `2016-01-06`...`2017-01-01`. I use these as columns.

I want to look for the year (16), then month (01), then for next column look for year (16) again and month (2). Then I'd like to interpret the month as shortened month names, like Jan or Feb. Finally I'd want to join the data back together. So in the end it will work like this:

- 16 + 01 becomes Jan16
- 16 + 02 becomes Feb16
- 17 + 01 becomes Jan17

How can I do this without manually entering an if-else clause for each month of each year?

Comment: Check monthname function of formula, i almost forgot this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to hard code it - Use this formula to get the month and year:

```
MonthName(Month(CDateTime({Command.NextDueDate}))) +
  Right(Left({Command.NextDueDate},4),2);
```

Comment: I wrote something similar. `if  right(left({Command.NextDueDate},7), 2) = '01' then 'jan ' + mid({Command.NextDueDate}, 1,4)
else if right(left({Command.NextDueDate},7), 2) = '02' then 'feb'` How does this look? Would it be considered bad?

Comment: @PawelBor I would consider your code to be a lot more work than it needs to be. There's a much easier way to do things without using `if` `then` `else` or even `right` and `left`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use if/else statements when you can get the information through clever use of formulas. There are a few ways you can make Ankur's formula even better:

To get the short Month name, use: `MonthName(Month(CDateTime({Command.NextDueDate})),True)`
 The *True* at the end shortens the name to "Jan", "Feb", "Mar" and so on.

To get the Year, use `Year(CDateTime({Command.NextDueDate}))`

---

Combine the two formulas and it does *all* the work for you:

```
MonthName(Month(CDateTime({Command.NextDueDate})),True) +
  Year(CDateTime({Command.NextDueDate}))
```